# Derivative of 'inside' matrix in the squared Frobenius norm of a product of three matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, trace

How does one approach finding $\nabla_X\|AXB\|_F^2$?

Normally I would expand to $\|AXB\|_F^2=\text{Trace}(B^TX^TA^TAXB)$ and rearrange using the cyclic property of traces to make $X$ the first and/or last matrix in the product, but this isn't possible here.

$A$ is wide and $B$ is tall; both are full-rank. $X$ is square. All matrices are real-valued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up formula (116) in the [Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf):

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial X}
\operatorname{tr}(
B^T X^T C X B
)    =
C^T X B B^T + C X B B^T$$

So, the answer is:

$$2 A^T A X B B^T$$

Answer (score 0):

Use a colon as a convenient product notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= {\rm Tr}(A^TB) \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
}$$
and, for typing convenience, define the matrix
$\;Y = AXB$.

Write the cost function in terms of this new variable, then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \big\|Y\big\|^2_F = Y:Y \\
d\phi &= 2Y:dY = 2Y:A\,dX\,B = 2A^TYB^T:dX \\
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial X} &= 2A^TYB^T = 2A^TAXBB^T \\
}$$